# exclude a pattern anywhere in a path returned by rglob

Tags: python

Is there a way to exclude a pattern from existing anywhere inside an rglob path:

```
for dir in Path(args.path).rglob("my_dir"):
    print(dir)


/home/user/path/to/this/my_dir
/home/user/bad/path/to/my_dir
/home/user//path/to/other/my_dir
```

This show all in rglob, but is the following possible?:

```
for dir in Path(args.path).rglob("[!bad]my_dir"):
    print(dir)

/home/user/path/to/this/my_dir
/home/user//path/to/other/my_dir
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After retrieving all the paths, you could use a regular expression (python `re` package) to match all path that contain `bad`, and add all the others to your final list.

The regex would be : `\/bad\/`

You could also use a simple if statement :

```py
for dir in Path(args.path).rglob("my_dir"):
    if "/bad/" in dir:
        print(dir)


/home/user/path/to/this/my_dir
/home/user/path/to/other/my_dir
```